# Google Maps API: how to get the street name in multiple languages

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to get the street name in multiple languages from the Google Maps API V3. For example in Belgium there are multilingual street names:

[image]

If i set the `language=FR` i will get "Rue Brogniez" and `language=NL` results "Brogniezstraat".

How can i get these names together in one `geocoder.geocode` call?

Answer (score 1):

You will find the answer by reading these two links: [Google Geocoder Region Codes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRegionCodes)
and [IANA language subtags](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry)

In real usage a request would look something like this:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({"address": your_address_string, "region": "NL"}, function(results, status){
    if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
        //do what you want to do here
        //to reach the full formatted address, use results[0].formatted_address
    }
})
```